# Cumulative distribution function and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

True or False:

Let $X$ be a Random variable.Then the function $G(t):=P(X \leq t)+\frac{P(X \geq t)}{2}$ is  right-continuous.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that $ G(t) = F_X(t) + \frac{1-F_X(t)}{2} + \frac{P(X=t)}{2} $. Is $ P(X=t) $ right continuous for every random variable $ X$?

Comment: Your four last questions on the site are completely lacking of context. Are you happy with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the random variable $X$ with
$$P(X=1)=1,\quad P(X\neq 1)=0.$$
Then for any $t>1$ we have
$$P(X\leq t)=1,\quad P(X\geq t)=0,$$
and therefore
$$\lim_{t\to 1^+}G(t)=1+\frac{0}{2}=1.$$
However
$$G(1)=P(X\leq 1)+\frac{P(X\geq 1)}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}.$$